# Como pegar o ultimo login de cada usuário utilizando mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `adm_historico_acesso` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(100),
  `codigo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

Gostaria de um `select` que mostrasse o seguinte resultado:

Exibir a última vez que cada `usuario` logou no sistema (baseado no campo date), sendo que o campo código é destinado para quando ele erra o `login`, então teria que exibir o último login válido e última tentativa de login com erro (o código teria o resultado `erro`).

Comment: Você quer o `último login com sucesso e com erro`, `de cada usuário`, é isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TODOS usuários com seus últimos logins de sucesso e de erro:

```
SELECT usuario, MAX(data) data, codigo
FROM adm_historico_acesso
WHERE codigo = 'erro'
GROUP BY usuario, codigo

UNION ALL

SELECT usuario, MAX(data) data, codigo
FROM adm_historico_acesso
WHERE codigo <> 'erro'
GROUP BY usuario, codigo
```

Comment: Perfeito, só inverti a ordem dos select para exibir sem erro primeiro, muito obrigado!

Comment: Rafael, você também pode dar um `select` colocando esse select todo dentro, e `filtrar ou ordenar` como quiser. Ex: `SELECT * FROM (**select acima**) ORDER BY usuario DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual a sua preocupação com desempenho, mas acho que uma consulta como esta não teria um prejuízo considerável usando `union`; se entendi correto, você quer o último login **com** e **sem** erro:

```
select top 1 id, data, codigo
from adm_historico_acesso
where codigo <> 'erro'
order by data desc
  union
select top 1 id, data, codigo 
from adm_historico_acesso
where codigo = 'erro'
order by data desc
union
```

Comment: Esse código deu erro na execução amigo.

Answer (score 0):

A `query` abaixo irá retornar uma linha para cada `codigo` diferente de um usuário:

```
SELECT a.`codigo`, MAX(a.`data`) `data` FROM `adm_historico_acesso` a
WHERE a.`usuario` = ''
GROUP BY a.`codigo`;
```

Basta colocar a referência do usuário entre as aspas simples.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seria algo assim que você precisa:

```
select MAX(data) as top, DATE(data), id, ip, usuario, codigo from
 `adm_historico_acesso` where codigo = '404';
```

Aqui tem um [**exemplo funcionando**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5136/1).